# Why setting BOOST_ROOT and Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS doesn't work but setting Boost_INCLUDE_DIR and Boost_LIBRARY_DIR

Tags: cmake, boost, build

I'm build `gtsam` under Win11 using Visual Studio and CMake, whick depends on Boost.
I downloaded Boost 1.81 from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.81.0_b1/boost_1_81_0_b1_rc2-msvc-14.3-64.exe/download).
In the CMakeLists.txt under root dir of `gtsam`, official hint show that

```
###############################################################################
# Find boost

# To change the path for boost, you will need to set:
# BOOST_ROOT: path to install prefix for boost
# Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS: set to true to keep the find script from ignoring BOOST_ROOT

# If using Boost shared libs, disable auto linking
if(MSVC)
    # Some libraries, at least Boost Program Options, rely on this to export DLL symbols
    # Disable autolinking
    if(NOT Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS)
        add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)
      add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK)
    endif()
endif()

find_package(Boost 1.43 COMPONENTS serialization system filesystem thread program_options date_time regex timer chrono)
```

What I set according to the hint is

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "D:/third_party/boost_1_81_0_b1_rc2/lib64-msvc/cmake")
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS true)
```

But it doesn't work. The error is

```
严重性 文件  代码  说明  项目  行   禁止显示状态
错误  C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake     CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR serialization system
  filesystem thread program_options date_time regex timer chrono) (Required
  is at least version "1.81")       230
```

What actually works is

```
#set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "D:/third_party/boost_1_81_0_b1_rc2/boost")
#set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR "D:/third_party/boost_1_81_0_b1_rc2/lib64-msvc")
```

Why the first one doesn't work but the second one? What's the different between them?

Comment: `# BOOST_ROOT: path to install prefix for boost` - You need to specify **installation prefix** in that variable, not the directory with `boost-config.cmake` script. Most likely the installation prefix in your case is `D:/third_party/boost_1_81_0_b1_rc2`.